# Multiple roles in mvc not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I am using

```
Authorize[Roles = "Agent")]
```

Which has always worked fine, however now I am to check if they are also in the paid usergroup I thought I could just do this:

```
Authorize[Roles = "Agent, Paid")]
```

However the above isnt working, it seems to be checking if I am in any of them roles instead of if I am in both. What do I do here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should do your custom `Authorize Attribute`

```
public class AuthorizeMultipleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

   //Authorize multiple roles
   public string MultipleRoles { get; set; }

  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
      var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
      if (!isAuthorized)
      {                
        return false;
      }

      //Logic here
      //Note: Make a split on MultipleRoles, by ','
      //User is in both roles => return true, else return false
  }

}
```

DEMO :

```
[AuthorizeMultiple(MultipleRoles ="Agent,Paid")]
```

Comment: I am not understanding how to do the logic, I know I must check if there in roles if not return false but how do I get the roles to check against ?